# nginx installing wordpress in a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nuxt.js

I am having a website running on tomcat, and I want to set my blog under a sub-directory of same website as `example.com/blog`

I tried using multiple settings for it, but none is working. Some gives 502 error, some 404 and following configuration gives No input file specified error.

```
root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    server_name 182.71.214.253;

    location /blogs {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /blogs/index.php?$args;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /var/www/html;
        #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME          
     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             include fastcgi_params;

    }}
```

Comment: Is there a file at `/var/www/html/blogs/index.php`? If not, where is WordPress installed?

Comment: wordpress folder is situated at ```/var/www/html/wordpress/```